# Как сложить все элементы массива? C++

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня есть задача: сложить все элементы массива заранее не зная сколько их и потом эту сумму сделать значением переменной. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Где ваш код? Что в нем не получается?

Comment: Вообще говоря, задача достаточно простая, попробуйте её решить сами, если не получится, вставьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Нужно больше деталей. Откуда берутся числа? Будь они на самом деле уже в массиве, такой вопрос вряд ли возник. Они вводятся в консоль, или может из файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), double());
```

Вот и все!
Раз вы не написали свой код, то вы можете получать и ответы, которые могут быть для вас не понятны.